# Best option for PDF viewer embedded in web app

Tags: web-development, asp.net, web-applications, silverlight

I have a web app that needs to be able to display a PDF.  It needs to allow the user to page through the PDF, and my application needs to be able to know which page is currently being viewed, because other aspects of the web app will change based on the current page.  Ideally it would not be dependent on the client having Adobe Reader but I could probably support that dependency.

What are my best options for this?  My application stack consists of ASP.NET 4 along with optionally Silverlight 5.  Also, I could use something that is client-side based as well using JavaScript / HTML if such a thing exists.

I found [ComponentOne's offering](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/PdfViewerSilverlight/) for this and that seems like the leading candidate at this point, but I want to know if there are other options I should consider.

Edit: Per Fosco's comment, converting the PDF to another format (such as HTML) might be an option, as long as I could tie back parts of the converted document to the original PDF page #s.

Another note: this has to run entirely on our servers.  It would not be acceptable to use a third-party service to view the PDFs.

Comment: With all of the browser/plug-in considerations you might also want to investigate on-the-fly conversion from PDF to HTML.

Comment: @Fosco, if there is a good library for that I would definitely take a look at it.  Do you have any recommendations?  It would only be useful if post-conversion I could tie back particular parts of the HTML doc to specific page #s from the PDF.

Comment: Considering that everyone already has a PDF viewer on their desktop, this seems rather silly.  Why not just download the PDF and be done with it?

Comment: @S.Lott because the web application stores metadata about the PDF on a per-page basis, and the user interacts with the web application to affect that metadata based on the current page that the user is looking at.  I *could* script all this on the client side I imagine using Adobe Reader but I'd prefer to have this all running in a web app.

Comment: @S.Lott - Everyone has a PDF reader, apart from those that don't.

Comment: Why a PDF ? This looks like normal web pages:  I fill some form, hit "next", then I see another page, customized using what I previously inputted.

Comment: Well, this was on a system I was working on over a year ago, but basically there were existing PDFs that we were pulling from a document repository.  Converting all of them to web pages was not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suspicion is that if you want to keep track of the page, and do other things, you'll have to get away from PDF in the browser. Based on what you've said, probably the easiest solution will be to extract pages from the PDF as images (perhaps preprocess the PDFs and store each page image separately), then use a Silverlight control to show the pages one by one. A possible starting place is [this codeproject sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/pdftoimages.aspx). According to some other StackOverflow answers, it is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714905/can-itextsharp-rasterize-export-to-jpeg-or-other-image-format) to do this with iText.

Comment: This is definitely one of the design options I am considering.  Thanks for the sample link.

Answer (score 5):

There's been a lot of buzz around [pdf.js](https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js) recently, a javascript PDF renderer for html 5.

It is a very young project, it is not yet suitable for real world usage, and it requires a recent browser. But in a long term, that may be a viable solution for your problem.

**UPDATE**

pdf.js is now [integrated into Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2013/01/11/mozilla-tests-a-built-in-secure-pdf-viewer-in-firefox-beta-leveraging-the-power-of-html5/) as the default built in PDF viewer.

Comment: Interesting link barjak.  I agree long term this library might be interesting but it is too immature at this point.  But this is definitely the type of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

PDF.JS is not exactly a plug and play operation, you're better off converting the PDFs to HTML. There's also things you can pay for.

What I reccomend to anyone looking to embed a PDF in a webpage with minimal configuarion is [Google Docs Viewer.](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html)

Advantage: Easy like Sunday Morning, beautiful 
Disadvantage: Hosted by Google